# How to get session message success and cart in Inertia react

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

how do i get the message of success and the cart

```
public function cart(Request $request)
{
    $validasi = $request->validate([
        "order_quantity" => "required",
        "total_amount" => "required",
    ]);
    $validasi["user_id"] = Auth::user()->id;
    $res = [];
    foreach ($request->product_id as $id) {
        $product = Product::find($id['id']);
        $product->stock = $product->stock - $id['stock'];
        $product->save();
        $data = [
            "user_id" => $validasi['user_id'],
            "product_id" => $id['id'],
            "order_quantity" => $validasi['order_quantity'],
            "total_amount" => $validasi['total_amount'],
        ];
        $res[] = Cart::create($data);
    }
    if ($res) {
        return redirect("/cashier")->with([
            "success" => "Data berhasil dibuat.",
            "cart" => $res
        ]);
    }
    return redirect("/cashier")->with("error", "Data gagal dibuat.");
}
```

how do i get the success message and cart detail after success ?

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601943/how-to-return-simple-flash-message-with-inertia-react-laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return simple Flash message with Inertia React & Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601943/how-to-return-simple-flash-message-with-inertia-react-laravel)