# Displaying success message from laravel backend to react frontend

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

i have a problem i hope some can help

so am learning laravel + react full stack development where am using laravel for my back end and react for the frontend but am stuck at this point..
i have NoteController class

```php
class NoteController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, string $uuid)
    {
        //
        //validate
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required | max:120',
            'text' => 'required'
        ]);
        // Retrieve the existing note from the database
        $note = Note::where('uuid', $uuid)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->firstOrFail();
        // Update the note attributes with the new data from the request
        $note->title = $request->title;
        $note->text = $request->text;
        $note->update();

        return to_route('notes.show', $uuid)->with('success', 'Note Updated Successfully');
    }
}
```

i have the route for all end points

```php
Route::resource('/notes', NoteController::class)->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

then i have my frontend code

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/react";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import TextInput from "@/Components/TextInput";
import SecondaryButton from "@/Components/SecondaryButton";
import DangerButton from "@/Components/DangerButton";

export default function ViewNote({ auth, note, success }) {
    const csrfToken = document
        .querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')
        .getAttribute("content");
         // useEffect to clear success message after a certain time
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            success = null;
        }, 3000); // 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, [success]);
    const getTimeDifference = (updatedAt) => {
        const updatedAtDateTime = DateTime.fromISO(updatedAt, { zone: "utc" });
        const now = DateTime.now();

        // Check if the updated_at time is in the future
        if (updatedAtDateTime > now) {
            return "Updated in the future";
        }

        const diff = now.diff(updatedAtDateTime, [
            "years",
            "months",
            "days",
            "hours",
            "minutes",
            "seconds",
        ]);

        const units = [
            { unit: "years", label: "y" },
            { unit: "months", label: "M" },
            { unit: "days", label: "d" },
            { unit: "hours", label: "h" },
            { unit: "minutes", label: "m" },
            { unit: "seconds", label: "s" },
        ];

        for (const { unit, label } of units) {
            const value = diff.get(unit);
            if (value >= 1) {
                return diff.toFormat(`${value} '${label} ago'`);
            }
        }

        // If the time difference is less than one second
        return diff.toFormat("s 'seconds ago'");
    };

    return (
        <AuthenticatedLayout
            user={auth.user}
            header={
                <h2 className="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                    Notes
                </h2>
            }
        >
            <Head title="View Note" />

            <div className="py-12">
            {success && (
                    <div
                        className="bg-green-100 border border-green-400 text-green-700 px-4 py-3 rounded relative"
                        role="alert"
                    >
                        <span className="block sm:inline">{success}</span>
                    </div>
                )}
                <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <p className="opacity-70 ml-8">
                            <strong>Created at : </strong>
                            {getTimeDifference(note.created_at)}
                        </p>
                        <p className="opacity-70 ml-8">
                            <strong>Updated at : </strong>
                            {getTimeDifference(note.updated_at)}
                        </p>
                        <a
                            href={route("notes.edit", note.uuid)}
                            className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 focus:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2 transition ease-in-out duration-150
                             ml-auto"
                        >
                            Edit
                        </a>
                        <form
                            action={route("notes.destroy", note.uuid)}
                            method="post"
                            onSubmit={(e) => {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                if (
                                    window.confirm(
                                        "Are you sure you want to delete the task?"
                                    )
                                ) {
                                    fetch(route("notes.destroy", note.uuid), {
                                        method: "DELETE",
                                        headers: {
                                            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken,
                                        },
                                    })
                                        .then((response) => {
                                            if (response.ok) {
                                                // Success: Show success message
                                                alert(
                                                    "Note deleted successfully"
                                                );
                                                // Redirect to notes index route if necessary
                                                window.location.href = "/notes";
                                            } else {
                                                // Failure: Show error message
                                                alert("Failed to delete note");
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .catch((error) => {
                                            // Error: Show error message
                                            alert(
                                                "An error occurred while deleting the note"
                                            );
                                            console.error("Error:", error);
                                        });
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name="_method"
                                value="DELETE"
                            />
                            <TextInput
                                type="hidden"
                                name="_token"
                                value={csrfToken}
                            />
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                className="ml-4 inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-red-500 active:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:ring-offset-2 transition ease-in-out duration-150"
                            >
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className=" my-6 p-6 border-b border-gray-200 bg-white  shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg"
                        key={note.id}
                    >
                        <h2 className="font-bold text-5xl">{note.title}</h2>
                        <p className="mt-6 whitespace-pre-wrap">{note.text}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </AuthenticatedLayout>
    );
}
```

so what am trying to achieve is that when a user updates the note .. i display a success message .. i have used the with method to **Redirect With Flashed Session Data** but my problem is that i can't seem to get the message on the frontend ... success props is always undefined or null ... can someone help me indentify what am doing wrong and how to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return simple Flash message with Inertia React & Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601943/how-to-return-simple-flash-message-with-inertia-react-laravel)

Comment: inertia does not return flash message by default. You would need to check `HandleInertiaRequests` for you to fetch the key from flash session

Comment: i saw the answer you are referencing but i don't understand how i would implement it in my case if you can provide a guide it will be heplful

Comment: Did you try to update the `HandleInertiaRequests` like what it did in the answer? Did you check the props **after** the changes in `HandleInertiaRequests` ?

Comment: i  don't know what am supposed to use the HandleInertiaRequests like its implementation i have tried but i don't what to do with it

Comment: Did you check the link I sent you? Scrolled down to an answer? On the answer part, inside the `share` method, include flash.